# Change Button Text in MessageBox

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, messagebox

When I use the AfxMessageBox with MB_OK the messagebox is shown with 'ok' as button text and when i use the MB_YESNO it is shown with 'Oui' for Ok and 'Annuler' for No (I am running under French Windows).

I want to know if I could change the text button of my MessageBow without creating a custom one? or is it possible to hide the cancel button when i use the MB_YESNO?

Comment: Oui means Yes, not OK.  You can't change the button text, it is preset by the language of the operating system.  MB_YESNO does not produce a Cancel button, MB_YESNOCANCEL does.

Comment: yes you are right about the text messages french/english traduction :)

So I guess I have to use a Visual Studio in FR !!!

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: No. And that does not make any sense. It depends on the language settings on the computer the application you developed will be run.